# No keyword with name '${body}= Create Dictionary' found

Tags: python, api, selenium, automation, robotframework

```
*** settings ***

Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  Collections
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${username}     XXXXXX

${password}     YYYYYY

${locale}       ZZZZ


*** test cases ***

TC1

            ${body}= Create Dictionary  username=       ${username}  password=      ${password}
            ${header}= Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*    Content-Type=application/json, Accept-Language=${locale},   
            Create Session OA2  ${base_url}
            ${response}= post request   OA2 /oauth/v2/token   data=     ${body}    headers=     ${header}
            log to console  ${response.status_code}
            log to console  ${response.content}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must follow [space separated format](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-separated-format).

In following code line (and others) you seem to only use 1 space between variable and keyword `${body}= Create Dictionary`.
That's why robot can not parse the code correctly and the error is raised.
Expand that code to use at least 2 space separation.
You should try the code like this.
    `${body}=  Create Dictionary  username=${username}  password=${password}`

And of course revise rest of the code accordingly.

I also recommend you study the user guide.
It contains a lot of useful information.